# Concatenate text from cells belonging to a range of "True" values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question that I don't know how to approach and solve. I have a dataframe with two columns, Text and Binary. I want to generate a third one that will concatenate the strings from the Text cells in a range of 3 "True" values above and below the current row by including the false values in that range.

This is what I would like to have at the end:

| Text | Binary | Generated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | True | **ABC** EFG KLM OPQ FGA KLA UTF GBD XXX KLJ |
| EFG | True | ABC **EFG** KLM OPQ FGA KLA UTF GBD XXX KLJ OPR ABB DAE |
| KLM | *False* | ABC EFG **KLM** OPQ FGA KLA UTF GBD XXX KLJ OPR ABB DAE |
| OPQ | *False* | ABC EFG KLM **OPQ** FGA KLA UTF GBD XXX KLJ OPR ABB DAE |
| FGA | True | ABC EFG KLM OPQ **FGA** KLA UTF GBD XXX KLJ OPR ABB DAE QWE RTE LLK |
| KLA | *False* | ABC EFG KLM OPQ FGA **KLA** UTF GBD XXX KLJ OPR ABB DAE QWE RTE LLK |
| UTF | True | ABC EFG KLM OPQ FGA KLA **UTF** GBD XXX KLJ OPR ABB DAE QWE RTE LLK LMN |
| GBD | *False* | ABC EFG KLM OPQ FGA KLA UTF **GBD** XXX KLJ OPR ABB DAE QWE RTE LLK LMN |
| XXX | *False* | ABC EFG KLM OPQ FGA KLA UTF GBD **XXX** KLJ OPR ABB DAE QWE RTE LLK LMN |
| KLJ | *False* | ABC EFG KLM OPQ FGA KLA UTF GBD XXX **KLJ** OPR ABB DAE QWE RTE LLK LMN |
| OPR | True | EFG KLM OPQ FGA KLA UTF GBD XXX KLJ **OPR** ABB DAE QWE RTE LLK LMN |
| ABB | *False* | EFG KLM OPQ FGA KLA UTF GBD XXX KLJ OPR **ABB** DAE QWE RTE LLK LMN |
| DAE | *False* | EFG KLM OPQ FGA KLA UTF GBD XXX KLJ OPR ABB **DAE** QWE RTE LLK LMN |
| QWE | True | FGA KLA UTF GBD XXX KLJ OPR ABB DAE **QWE** RTE LLK LMN |
| RTE | *False* | FGA KLA UTF GBD XXX KLJ OPR ABB DAE QWE **RTE** LLK LMN |
| LLK | *False* | FGA KLA UTF GBD XXX KLJ OPR ABB DAE QWE RTE **LLK** LMN |
| LMN | True | UTF GBD XXX KLJ OPR ABB DAE QWE RTE LLK **LMN** |

Any help is appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: As I'm trying to follow your logic, shouldn't rows 7,8,9 `[GBD, XXX, KLJ]` start with `EFG` instead of `ABC`? Because the three `True` values above are rows 1,4,6 `[EFG, FGA, UTF]`?

Comment: I had same reaction as @Simon : the Generated value of the row with index GBD should begin only with EFG KLM OPQ.... because there are 4 True above this row: in rows of indexes ABC , EFG , FGA , UTF. This first one (ABC) should be excluded from the Generated value in this said row.

Comment: UTF GBD XXX and KLJ belong to the same group (or range). It was a complicated one and Valdi_Bo's answer solved my problem. Thank you all

Comment: Dorothy, your comment about UTF GBD XXX KLJ has absolutely no relation to what me and Simon pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create an auxiliary *Series*:

```
cs = df.Binary.cumsum()
```

Then, to generte your new column, run:

```
df['Generated'] = cs.apply(lambda n: df.Text[cs.between(n-3, n+3)].str.cat(sep=' '))
```

By default *Pandas* imposes some limit on the width of each column, so "ordinary"
printing will not show full content.

But if you run:

```
with pd.option_context("display.max_colwidth", 70):
    print(df)
```

you will get something like:

```
    Text  Binary  Generated
0   ABC   True    ABC EFG KLM OPQ FGA KLA UTF GBD XXX KLJ 
1   EFG   True    ABC EFG KLM OPQ FGA KLA UTF GBD XXX KLJ OPR ABB DAE 
2   KLM   False   ABC EFG KLM OPQ FGA KLA UTF GBD XXX KLJ OPR ABB DAE 
3   OPQ   False   ABC EFG KLM OPQ FGA KLA UTF GBD XXX KLJ OPR ABB DAE 
4   FGA   True    ABC EFG KLM OPQ FGA KLA UTF GBD XXX KLJ OPR ABB DAE QWE RTE LLK 
5   KLA   False   ABC EFG KLM OPQ FGA KLA UTF GBD XXX KLJ OPR ABB DAE QWE RTE LLK 
6   UTF   True    ABC EFG KLM OPQ FGA KLA UTF GBD XXX KLJ OPR ABB DAE QWE RTE LLK LMN 
7   GBD   False   ABC EFG KLM OPQ FGA KLA UTF GBD XXX KLJ OPR ABB DAE QWE RTE LLK LMN 
8   XXX   False   ABC EFG KLM OPQ FGA KLA UTF GBD XXX KLJ OPR ABB DAE QWE RTE LLK LMN 
9   KLJ   False   ABC EFG KLM OPQ FGA KLA UTF GBD XXX KLJ OPR ABB DAE QWE RTE LLK LMN 
10  OPR   True    EFG KLM OPQ FGA KLA UTF GBD XXX KLJ OPR ABB DAE QWE RTE LLK LMN 
11  ABB   False   EFG KLM OPQ FGA KLA UTF GBD XXX KLJ OPR ABB DAE QWE RTE LLK LMN 
12  DAE   False   EFG KLM OPQ FGA KLA UTF GBD XXX KLJ OPR ABB DAE QWE RTE LLK LMN 
13  QWE   True    FGA KLA UTF GBD XXX KLJ OPR ABB DAE QWE RTE LLK LMN 
14  RTE   False   FGA KLA UTF GBD XXX KLJ OPR ABB DAE QWE RTE LLK LMN 
15  LLK   False   FGA KLA UTF GBD XXX KLJ OPR ABB DAE QWE RTE LLK LMN 
16  LMN   True    UTF GBD XXX KLJ OPR ABB DAE QWE RTE LLK LMN
```

Actually, for readability, I changed the column alignment to "left".

## Edit

If you want yet shorter code, you can shorten it to the following one-liner:

```
df['Generated'] = (cs := df.Binary.cumsum()).apply(
    lambda n: df.Text[cs.between(n-3, n+3)].str.cat(sep=' '))
```

For readability I folded it into 2 lines, but it is a **single** instruction.

Comment: Thank you so much! The long one works, the short one returns an error at "(cs := " but it is perfectly fine. One last question, do you know if I can include the <b></b> tags in the middle one?
Thanks a lot; it means a lot to me

Comment: As far as "<b>" tags are concerned: *Pandas* is rather a database application not a web application, so You can format particular cells but not a part of the cell content. And now go to the error in my short solution: ":=" operator has been introduced in *Python* version **3.8**. I suppose that you have an older *Python* version. Upgrade it and the second solution should also work. And don't forget to accept my answer.

Comment: @Valdi_Bo : your result corresponds to the table given as example by Dorothy, but the example given by Dorothy doesn't correspond to her statement which asks for '3 "True" values above and below the current row'.  Cf my comment to her question

Comment: Valdi_Bo thanks a lot for the feedback!